# Committing from VS Code GUI vs git commit

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, azure-devops

I setup a remote repository in VS Code. It is pointing to Azure DevOps. I can stage a file using the GUI, but when I attempt to commit (click the check mark), I get this message:

```
No secret key
gpg: signing failed: No secret key
error: gpg failed to sign the data
fatal: failed to write commit object
```

However, if I open the terminal (ctrl-~), I can type this and it works:

```
git commit -m "my message"
```

I have searched for the gpg messages above but haven't found a solution. Any thoughts on what to try now? Is there any additional info you need?

Edit: solved by going to VS Code settings and searched for gpg. "Git: Enable Commit Signing" was checked. I un-checked it and now commits work from VS Code.

Comment: When you commit manually, is the commit GPG-signed? (Do you have `commit.gpgSign` set in your configuration?) If not, perhaps the GUI is turning on GPG signing and your command line commit isn't.

Comment: When I type this: git config commit.gpgsign, it returns false. So I assume I do NOT have commit.gpgSign set. I assume this is for the command line. How do I check in VS Code?

Comment: Not sure about VScode. I generally avoid all IDEs and don't have VSCode to experiment with. But if this is specifically a VSCode issue, you'd want a VSCode tag.

Comment: If it's the GUI requiring a signing key while git itself is configured not to require one, then VS Code has its own way of configuring Git options, one it doesn't share with Git.